# How to create large number sockets C?

Tags: c, sockets, asynchronous, asyncsocket

I am coding **asynchronous scanner ports**, that can scan a lot of ports. However, when I am making a lot of sockets, function socket() return -1.
That's simple code, that's giving error:

```cpp
#define ASYNC_SIZE 5000
    int*scks = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*ASYNC_SIZE); 
    for(int i = 0; i < ASYNC_SIZE; i++){
        if((scks[i] = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 ){
            printf("socket error\n"); 
            exit(0); 
        }
    }
```

I am getting EMFILE, from errno-base.h:

```cpp
#define EMFILE      24  /* Too many open files */
```

Can i create a lot of sockets without error? Or should I use something another for this? Should I handle sockets by myself(without Linux) like a masscan?

Comment: Use `ulimit -n 6000`. But this is not the fastest way to make a port scanner. If you want to scan ports just use nmap.

Comment: If you really care about scanning a lot of ports in a short amount of time, you need something akin to masscan. Too many open files means too many file descriptors (you're either hitting the soft limit or maybe even the hard limit). They aren't infinite. Masscan is purpose built to do a single very specific network operation many many times, limited only by process memory (in theory). It also gets around buffer copies and additional TCP handshaking etc.

Comment: @user253751
nmap is very slow( . I cant use ulimit, because I want do all in my code.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED -  I making simple masscan, because i cant use something like  a masscan or zmap, i am coding mine

Comment: @Rainbow: *"I cant use ulimit, because I want do all in my code."* - ulimit is just using [setrlimit](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) which you can do directly in your code.

Comment: If your whole motivation for doing this is because "nmap is very slow", I'd urge you to reconsider. I'm no expert on it, but nmap is _the_ community/industry accepted tool for mapping networks and port scanning (certainly a leader at least). It has a bazillion options and scan techniques, if you tweak those a certain way I'm sure you can speed it up. Slower scans are generally stealthier, so it may default to that behavior. If you're writing a port scanner for your own edification, forget I said anything.

Comment: @yano, hi. I love nmap) However I am writing scanner for my program(I need small size, so I dont include any libraries and programs aka nmap, masscan).